# Can not install psycopg2 on Mac 12.3, I keep getting this error

Tags: python-3.x, django, backend, psycopg2

Ive recently bought a MacBook Pro and was setting it up for some python and Django programming but I ended up having problems installing psycopg2, I've tried several things already and none of those worked for me, here left the error,

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /private/var/folders/7f/ssr40bmj6t3_yq0cv_43cttc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-noe7l09b/psycopg2.egg-info
      writing /private/var/folders/7f/ssr40bmj6t3_yq0cv_43cttc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-noe7l09b/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/7f/ssr40bmj6t3_yq0cv_43cttc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-noe7l09b/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/7f/ssr40bmj6t3_yq0cv_43cttc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-noe7l09b/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/7f/ssr40bmj6t3_yq0cv_43cttc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-noe7l09b/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      
      Error: pg_config executable not found.
      
      pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
      containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
      option:
      
          python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
      
      or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
      
      If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
      'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
      
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It shows it is not a problem with pip but with setup.py but can not find anything,

any help would be welcomed

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the message? It tells you you could try `psycopg2-binary` instead. That package will still install `psycopg2` as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: AKX I did try, even I first tried installing psycopg2-binary before just pscopg2, because I do have an environment in windows and linux, and linux required to install psycopg2-binary instead of just psycopg2. But yes, I tried

Comment: What do you mean with "environment in windows and Linux"? How does that relate to your MacBook? (Is it an Intel machine or with Apple Silicon?)

Comment: Yes, it is an apple silicon, it is the M1, and when I said the environment I meant that I have everything working fine, everything installed and working perfectly, including psycopg2, Im new to MacOS so Im struggling with some installations

Comment: This issue might help, then. I found it by googling `psycopg2 m1`. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1286

Comment: i have the same problem, any solution? the answer from the above link doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem on an Apple MacBookPro M1

Answer (score 10):

As Alex mentioned, it is PostGreSQL being not installed on your system that throws up the error
Install PostGreSQL and it will all work fine
Try this

````
❯ brew install postgresql
# If you open a new terminal tab you will see that pg_config is available
❯ export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
❯ export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib"
❯ python -V
Python 3.9.13
❯ pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.6```
````

Answer (score 9):

Try using the following command:

```
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Late, but I just had this problem and nothing I was finding was fixing it. I was trying to install the requirements.txt for an ongoing project on a new Mac. Eventually I remembered it's a postgresql package and I hadn't installed postgresql yet. As soon as I installed postgresql and tried installing psycopg2 again, it worked fine with no errors.